# key value pair position change when converting sorted ordereddict to dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary

So I need to convert my dictionary to a dictionary sorted by values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
d = {"third": 3, "first": 1, "fourth": 4, "second": 2}
d_sorted_by_value = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))

# OrderedDict([('first': 1), ('second': 2), ('third': 3), ('fourth': 4)])
# print (OrderedDict)
def ordereddict_to_dict(d_sorted_by_value):
    for k, v in d_sorted_by_value.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d_sorted_by_value[k] = ordereddict_to_dict(v)
    print dict(d_sorted_by_value)
d = {"third": 3, "first": 1, "fourth": 4, "second": 2}
d_sorted_by_value = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
print d_sorted_by_value
ordereddict_to_dict(d_sorted_by_value)
```

On printing d_sorted_by_value I get: 
`OrderedDict([('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3), ('fourth', 4)])`

which is not what i want even though it can be used as a dict. 
So the function to convert it to dict was called whch gave me the following output:

```
{'second': 2, 'third': 3, 'fourth': 4, 'first': 1}
```

As you can see the key value pair: 'first':1' beomes the last element on conversion, what am i doing worng here? The desired output that i want is :

```
{'first': 1,'second': 2, 'third': 3, 'fourth': 4}
```

Please guide in the right direction. Thanks!!

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered data structures. That's why OrderedDict exists at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.

A `dict` object in Python <3.7 is not considered to be ordered. It is internally ordered in 3.6, but this is considered an implementation detail.

Converting a `dict` to an `OrderedDict` and then back to a `dict` object should not be assumed to maintain order.

Your options are:

1. Use regular `dict` for an unordered collection.
2. Use `OrderedDict` for an ordered collection.

Comment: will it be possible to append the last key-value pair on a dict to the beginning of the dict? if so, how can it be done?

Comment: @CouchPotato95, No, that's not possible. Dictionaries are not considered to be ordered pre Python 3.7. Use `OrderedDict` without converting back to `dict`.